# A strange NullPointerException

Tags: android

I'm working on an android app where I have only 2 activities... The first activity call the second activity.. At the start my app initialize a global ArrayList with some informations taken over the internet... then a thread starts and every 10 seconds fetch the same informations and updates the ArrayList ( thread doesn't allocate it again )... When I start the second activity, this one fetch the ArrayList at the start... this works in my emulator and my phone ( htc wildfire ) but for someone that has my app, this works only for about 20 minutes, after that the ArrayList become null... why this?? oh btw, the ArrayList is a CopyOnWrite ArrayList, if could be important...

Thanks in advance for any reply,

=.4.S.=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a guess due to the lack of details you're posting, but most probably your first Activity is being killed and thus the ArrayList is collected by the GC.

Comment: I thought the same ^^ but why GC must kill my activity?? should close the entire app... and apart that ArrayList is global and defined in a global class that extends Application...declaring it static could solve the matter??

Comment: If it's a field in an Application instance then it's not that reason. I would suggest you to add as much detail as you can to the question, so we can figure out what's going on.

Comment: Oh and sorry for the lack of details....the app code is being big, you can find it here http://code.google.com/p/somadroid/source/checkout and the app here https://market.android.com/details?id=org.as.somadroid

Comment: As you can see in somadroidApp class there's a ChannelFactory object that contains the ArrayList of Channels, that are fetched by a thread in the main activity, Somadroid... Somadroid can launch PlayRadio, that onCreate fetch the ChannelFactory, and sometimes throw the exception...

Comment: May the CopyOnWrite ArrayList saturate the memory?? ( CopyOnWrite should make a copy everytime I modify something, right? ) so GC is obliged to remove the ArrayList?

Comment: Yes, it makes a copy with each modification, but unless it's a huge list I don't think that should be an issue. Also, the GC would collect anything else that is not in use. Since the application is in use, it won't touch it's fields (unless it kills the app altogether)

Comment: Is the exception in this line: `channel = ((SomadroidApp)this.getApplication()).channel_factory.getChannels().get(n_channel);` ? Are you sure the list is null and not its content?

Comment: Yes, it is ^^ I'm sure because list is allocated only at the app starting, after that every element is updated by the thread...